# Unable to use exedit popup in angular bootstrap project

Tags: x-editable, angularjs-bootstrap

How to use xeditable popup in angular bootstrap project?
followed steps mentioned in http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/docs.html
It gives the error : ReferenceError: $ is not defined

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting

Comment: Did you add jquery? It has a jquery dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add jquery? It has a jquery dependency.